# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'querySelectorAll')at Number.handleHover

Tags: javascript, typeerror, undefined, selectors-api

I have some JavaScrupt code that gives this error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'querySelectorAll')at Number.handleHover
.

```
 const handleHover = function (e) {
      if (e.target.classList.contains('nav-link')) {
        const link = e.target;
        const sibling = link
          .closest('.nav-wrap')
          .document.querySelectorAll('.nav-link');
        sibling.forEach(el => {
          if (el !== link) el.style.opacity = this;
        });
      }
    };
navSmooth.addEventListener('mouseover', handleHover.bind(0.5));
navSmooth.addEventListener('mouseout', handleHover.bind(1));
```

Answer (score 0):

Well，you should delete “document” in sibling.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).